# Descriptive complexity characterization of TimeSpace classes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, descriptive-complexity

Are there [descriptive complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity_theory) characterizations for [TimeSpace](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aD#dtisp) complexity classes like [$\mathsf{SC^i}= \mathsf{DTimeSpace}(n^{O(1)},O(\lg^i n))$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aS#sc)?